# How are design-by-contract and property-based testing (QuickCheck) related?

Tags: testing, design-by-contract, xunit

Is their only similarity the fact that they are **not** xUnit (or more precisely, not based on enumerating specific test cases), or is it deeper than that?

Property-based testing (using QuickCheck, ScalaCheck, etc) seem well-suited to a functional programming style where side-effects are avoided. On the other hand, Design by Contract (as implemented in Eiffel) is more suited to OOP languages: you can express post-conditions about the *effects* of methods, not just their return values.

But both of them involve testing assertions that are true in general (rather than assertions that should be true for a specific test case). And both can be tested using randomly generated inputs (with QuickCheck this is the *only* way, whereas with Eiffel I believe it is an optional feature of the AutoTest tool).

Is there an umbrella term to encompass both approaches? Or am I imagining a relationship that doesn't really exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe one relationship lies in the concept of *Oracle* described by Bertrand Meyer, author of Eiffel, in "[Seven Principles of Software Testing](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/testing/principles.pdf)".

> A test run is only useful if you can unambiguously determine whether
>   it passed. The criterion is called a test oracle. If you have a few
>   dozen or perhaps a few hundred tests, you might afford to examine the
>   results individually, but this does not scale up. The task cries for
>   automation.
>
> **Principle 4: Applying oracle**
>   *Determining success or failure of tests must be an automatic process.*
>
> This statement of the principle leaves open the form of oracles.
>   Often, oracles are specified separately. In research such as ours,
>   they are built in, as the target software already includes contracts
>   that the tests use as oracles.
>
> **Principle 4 (variant): Contracts as oracles**
>   *Oracles should be part of the program text, as contracts. Determining test success or failure should be an automatic process consisting of
>   monitoring contract satisfaction during execution.*

- Based on this, I guess we could say QuickCheck and Eiffel's Auto Test both use automated test oracles but different *oracle forms*, the former being external to the production program (properties expressed in separate test suite) and the latter, built into the production program (contracts).
- From a historical perspective, we can assume that QuickCheck (first released in 1999) and earlier work on property-based testing dating back to the 90's served as inspiration to Eiffel's AutoTest (which appeared in 2008), although I couldn't find any firm evidence of that in Bertrand Meyer's papers or interviews.

Comment: Thanks for drawing this connection. So in a nutshell, design-by-contract and property-based testing both imply an *automated* means of checking of whether a test case meets the spec or not.

Comment: And even if the inspiration for AutoTest is not known, when the designer of Eiffel begins advocating randomized testing, we might call it a sign of convergence between design-by-contract and property-based testing.

Answer (score 3):

The relationship is that the combination of design by contract and the testing methods are attempting to substitute for a correctness proof, which would be the ultimate goal, if it were feasible. Pre-conditions and post-conditions (for return values) are useful even in methods with no side effects, as they limit input domains and output ranges.